# Php Mail is not sending the mail through which email id contain user@domain.in

Tags: php, email

```
$to="user@domain.in";
$subject="Entry Level Freshers Candidates";

// Get the sender's name and email address plug them a variable to be used later
$from = stripslashes($_POST['nfirst'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['email']).">";
$message = '<html><body>'; .........
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The above Php mail is working fine when email id is user@domain.com, But this not working when email id is user@domain.in.

May i have solution pls,

Comment: i see no problem as long as $to is corect, are you sure there is correct data in $to?

Comment: What is the content of `$headers`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the swiftmailer package on their site here -> http://swiftmailer.org/

```
require_once 'swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

function new_mail($subject, $content, $recipients, $from)
{

    // Create the message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

    // Give the message a subject
    $message->setSubject($subject);

    // Set the From address with an associative array
    $message->setFrom($from);

    // Set the To addresses with an associative array
    $message->setTo($recipients);

    // Give it a body
    $message->setBody($content);

    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $result = $mailer->send($message);

}

$message            = "Anything you want here.";
$recipients         = array('emailaddress@goeshere.com' => 'Your name of choice');
$subject            = "Subject goes here";
$from               = array('emailaddress@goeshere.com' => 'Name of choice.');

new_mail($subject, $message, $recipients, $from);
```

I revised this piece of code from my other answer. Let me know if this one works for you.

Comment: I need to work the mail process in basic phpmail, my question is the above phpmail is working perfectly when i use email id with .com in $to, but not working in email id with .in, i don't need the above solution, it should be work in basic php mail because am using these in joomla setup

Comment: Well from personal experience the basic mail() function has always been so buggy. I don't have a real explanation for your problem besides giving you an alternative function. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you can use the joomla version of swiftmailer?
http://www.findbestopensource.com/product/jswiftmailer

Comment: this ll worked in joomla 1.6 but am using joomla 2.5 no source :(